# R Code to Add a Special Header When Exporting a Matrix to a Text File

Tags: r, arcgis, export-to-text

I have code that is creating a 141 x 131 matrix from one big column and exporting it as a text file. So far it works good. I am going to import these files into ArcGIS using the ASCII to raster tool. For ArcGIS to import them a five line header is required, with the data following the header like this:

```
NCOLS 131
NROWS 141
XLLCENTER -150
YLLCENTER -70
CELLSIZE 1
NODATA_VALUE -32768
265 41.7 1.8 12 16 18.3 16.5 18.3 19.7 24.5 26.1 28.4...
```

It is trivial to manually paste in this header once R saves the text file, but I have over 900 files I need to process so I'd like to have R add the header when it exports the text file. Is that possible or can I just add the header lines as the first 5 rows of the matrix and then export it?

Edit: this section below is regarding an additional question I asked in the comments.

Here is my whole code:

```
batch_tpose <- function(filename) {
dat <- matrix(scan(file = filename),ncol=3,byrow=T)
dat_trans <- matrix(dat[,3], 141, byrow=FALSE)

header <- "NCOLS 131
NROWS 141
XLLCENTER -150
YLLCENTER -70
CELLSIZE 1
NODATA_VALUE -32768"

writeLines(header, filename)
write.table(dat_trans, file = filename, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)

## This works, I just need the output to be something like out/filename...


}

batch_tpose("200RelVort-nwatl-20201008-15.txt")
```

I want to be able to process a bunch of files in the `batch_tpose` command at the bottom using `list.files`. Right now I'm just testing with one file. This works but it writes the files to the working directory. It also overwrites the source file because it is in the same directory. How do I write the output files to the "out" directory? I've tried `out/filename` and `file = out/filename` but that creates a new file called "filename." I've tried other combinations but they caused errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first write the header with `readLines` and then the data with `write.table` (or a similar function). The trick is then the option `append = TRUE`. Here an example:

```
header <- "NCOLS 131
NROWS 141
XLLCENTER -150
YLLCENTER -70
CELLSIZE 1
NODATA_VALUE -32768"

data <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)

writeLines(header, "file.txt")
write.table(data, file="file.txt", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

You can also `paste` the header text with usual R functions together:

```
ncols=131
nrows=141

header <- paste0("NCOLS ", ncols, 
"\nNROWS ", nrows,
"\nXLLCENTER -150
YLLCENTER -70
CELLSIZE 1
NODATA_VALUE -32768")
```

Line breaks can either be specified as line breaks within the text string or with the newline "\n" code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give those a try.

Comment: Yes, it shoukdl work, as long as the header values remain the same.

Comment: Thankfully that does not need to change. I have all of the code in a function (using function(filename)) now so I can process multiple files. I'm having trouble with the filename syntax on the last lines. How do I change "file.txt" and file="file.txt" so that it writes in a folder called "out" with the original filename? I tried out/filename and file=out/filename and various combinations but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `"out/file.txt"` should work, given that it is in quotes (missed in your vomment), that R is already in the correct working folder (where out is relative to) and that an ordinary slash `/` is used and not a single backslash.

Comment: Yes "out/file.txt" works fine. I have this in a function now where I'm using "filename" to be the file or files that the function runs. How do I change the output statement where it grabs the actual filename through the filename call in the function. For instance, file = filename would work if I want to save it in the working folder, but file = out/filename doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure how to help here, because I don't know your background. Have you already created an "out" subfolder?

Comment: Sorry, the hardest part of all this for me is asking the right question. I do have an "out" subfolder. I updated my original question so that you can see the whole code now, maybe what I'm asking there will make more sense.

Comment: If `filename` is a character variable and `out` is constant, then use `paste0("out/",filename)`